# SessionID throws null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object that encapsulates a System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState object as one of its data members.  Rarely (to the point where we are unable to reproduce exactly when or how) we will get a NullReferenceException error with this object when accessing customSession.Session.SessionID

I've used the debugger to trace the object, and `customSession.Session` is not null.  It is a valid `HttpSessionState` object.

```
Mode: InProc

StaticObjects: {System.Web.HttpStaticObjectsCollection}

SyncRoot: {System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer}

Keys: {System.Collection.SpecializedNameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection}

IsNewSession: true

IsReadOnly: false
```

Keys has 4 records in it.

But even in the debugger, if I explore the object and try to get the SessionID, it says

> "cs.Session.SessionID threw an exception of type System.NullReferenceException.

Does anyone know if this is just a bug in Visual Studio's development server?  I just don't want to have this issue occur on a production release and the only way to fix it is to restart IIS.

-- Edit --

Additional information:

I'm using the "break when common language runtime exception is thrown" option, so what's happening is the system is trying to access the CustomSession object, as cs.Session.SessionID and getting a null-ref exception, and the debugger kicks in. Then I use the watch window and put in "cs.Session" in the watch, and it shows all the properties of the Session object, and the line for SessionID says it throws a null reference exception. This null ref exception causes the application to break if not manually handled.

I was able to reproduce the error by modifying code in the App_Code directory repeatedly (took about 5 or 6 changes I think).  I don't know for certain if this is the only way of this issue happening as others here have reported it happening after what they suspected was a session timeout.  In any case, it seems to be happening within the "Session_End" event coming out of the global.asax. But the error occurs before the "Session.Abandon()" statement is hit.

I have confirmed that I can access values stored in the session.  The only thing giving an error is accessing the SessionID.

--- Additional (oct30) ----

The line where the error occurs is the if-statement:

```
foreach (CustomSession cs in allSessions) {
    if (cs.Session.SessionID == curSession.Session.SessionID) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The "cs" and "curSession" objects are both not null, the "Session" property of each is also not null at this point.

Comment: When does this object get called?  It's not likely to be a Cassini issue but rather that the objet gets called at times when Session is not available.

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) help? It's related to the conditions for app domain restarts on IIS, which will cause all session states to be dropped.

Comment: @NikoDrašković:  It sounds like the OP isn't losing *an object in Session* so much as losing *Session itself*.

Comment: Loss of `Session` can happen. Your code needs to be prepared for it, and to not assume that `HttpContext.Current.Session` is always non-null.

Comment: @zimdanen The weird part is that the session itself isn't being lost.  It's just the session ID that is.  If I use the debugger, I can actually access the various items stored in the session by key, it's just the SessionID that gets a null ref exception.

Comment: You can hit a breakpoint and access the Session but have it throw an error when accessing SessionID?  (All while in the same breakpoint?)

Comment: I'm using the "break when common language runtime exception is thrown" option, so what's happening is the system is trying to access the CustomSession object, as cs.Session.SessionID and getting a null-ref exception, and the debugger kicks in.   Then I use the watch window and put in "cs.Session" in the watch, and it shows all the properties of the Session object, and the line for SessionID says it throws a null reference exception.

Comment: @NikoDrašković It may be related to the application restarting.  I was able to reproduce this error by editing code in app_code repeatedly.  I'm continuing to look into other causes.

Comment: I've got the same thing. here is my stack trace:
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager.CheckInitializeRequestCalled(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager.GetSessionID(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.DelayedGetSessionId()
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_SessionID()
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.get_SessionID()

Answer (score -1):

You are watching an exception which would be handled ordinarily by the framework.

Essentially it is implementing a per-connection singleton pattern using the exception to detect when the session does not exist. So it just uses the session object, and if that throws an exception, it creates one on the spot and carries on.

Since you have selected "break when exception is thrown" and presumably not selected "Just my code", it is breaking. Because you asked it to.

Comment: If I don't have the break on exception thrown option turned on, the application completely crashes when trying to access the session ID.  I had the option on to determine where and why the error was happening. :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey, post the code which causes the exception (i.e. the top line of YOUR code from the call stack when the exception is thrown.)

Comment: I've appended the code where it fails to the main article (formatting in comments doesn't really work well)

Comment: I'm getting the same exception as CodeMonkey, and it's not something that is being caught by the runtime